# TLS certificate in MySQL server

Tags: mysql, ssl-certificate

I use a MySQL server in a Virtual Machine in Google Cloud which communicates with a website.

Regarding TLS certification, what do I have to do for my MySQL server? I have read this: https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Configure+MySQL+SSL+Connections but I am not sure exactly what actions do I have to do to install it?

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are using "localhost" on your MySQL connection then you do not need a TLS certificate here because the communication between your script and your database is not travelling over the internet, it is "*locally hosted*"

Comment: No, it's not local. The server is hosted on a VM in my Google Cloud account. Furthermore, the website is hosted in another VM in my Google cloud account. So, site and MySQL db communicate each other over internet.